# Checking if the user is logged in every Activity and Fragment onCreate callback?

Tags: android, security, android-fragments, android-activity, firebase-authentication

I was advised to do, in each Activity and Fragment `onCreate` callback, an `if(signed_user_id == null) { showErrorPopIn(); startSplashScreenActivity(); return; }` (a check that the user is not logged in, in which case we display an error and redirect the user from the Android app to the splash screen, and we don't execute the rest of the Activity and Fragment code). This code would be used in all activities (except SplashScreen of course) and in all Fragments, in the `onCreate` method. Cf. another SO question ([Check if user is logged in on every activity, or only at the beginning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53519544/check-if-user-is-logged-in-on-every-activity-or-only-at-the-beginning)).

**But I find it makes the code a lot heavier, and it seems to be useless.** Indeed:

- A hacker can change the activity code and the fragment code and therefore remove this condition, right?
- And most importantly: checking that the user is logged in is only useful on the server side, not on the Android app side. Indeed, the critical points are the read and write accesses to the databases. But I don't give a damn if the not-connected user can see the graphical part of a Fragment or an Activity if this part doesn't display anything from a database or doesn't allow any modification in a database after a click on a button for example. Right?
  So in the end I can remove all those `if(signed_user_id == null)` conditions I've put in all my Fragments and Activities?

**PS 1 :** `signed_user_id` is just `FirebaseAuth::getInstance().getUser().getUId()` roughly.

**PS 2 :** if I'm right, it means the first answer of the above linked SO question should be edited to indicate to the original poster that it's useless to do these checks in Android app side.

Comment: There is no accepted answer in the question you linked. But if you think an answer to that question is wrong, why not comment on it there?

Comment: Sorry I have edited my question.

Comment: This is why you should be using security rules and ID token validation on the backend to check everything and never trust the client app.

Comment: @DougStevenson yes I indeed use Security Rules for Firestore and Firestorage, and also the context param auth.uid in Cloud Functions :) But moreover, i was using the `if(signed_user_id)` in my app (which I have just removed now because redundant + useless). However, just a question: what is "ID token validation on the backend" because I didn't read about it in the Firebase documentation?

Comment: It's very well documented. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens

Comment: @DougStevenson Yes I've just found this doc too. It begins with "If your Firebase client app communicates with a custom backend server" . I think I didn't read this doc until now because I don't use any custom backend server, only Cloud Functions, Firestore and Firebase :). Thank you anyway, I'll keep it in memory

Comment: Cloud Functions is a custom backend where you can use the Firebase Admin SDK to verify tokens.  There are even official samples of that on GitHub.  The instructions here apply to it as well when you're writing HTTP triggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this statement you make:

> And most importantly: checking that the user is logged in is only useful on the server side, not on the Android app side.

There are two reasons to check whether a user is authenticated and/or authorized:

1. To reject unauthorized operations. This check should always happen on the server, as malicious user could bypass the check if (only) implemented on the client.
2. To show the correct authentication/authorization state to the user, and to allow them to change it (within the rules of your application). These checks happen on the client.

The goal of the second type of check is to show your user a clear UI, and provide them a path forward.

For example, you'll typically want to detect if the user is signed in, and if not show them the sign-in screen of your app. If you don't do this, the first time they know something is wrong is when the database rejects their operation with a "access denied" or similar message. This latter flow *may* be correct for your app, but it is very common to detect sign-in state on start-up and then first get the user to sign in (either anonymously or identified).

Another example could be if you have a premium user level who are allowed to write more data to your database. Of course the actual check of whether a write is allowed should be done server-side. But you might want to update the UI in some way if a non-premium user has reached their limit, for example disabling the UI elements that would update the database (and thus fail), or maybe show them a "you've reached the limits of your plan, click here to upgrade" banner.

So neither the server-side check nor the client-side check is useless, but they serve different purposes. Server-side checks are *required* to ensure your data stays uncorrupted, and your business rules are followed. Client-side checks are *recommended* to give your users a better (UI) experience.

Comment: The problem is that I would have to put my client-side check in a lot of methods: 1) in lifecycle callbacks of Activites and Fragments (I could extend my `BaseActivity/BaseFragment` to inherit, and avoid code dupplication) . 2) In the Firestore / Firestorage accesses' callbacks, which are defined in my Activities/Fragments methods which are defined within their `onActivityCreated` or `onCreate` lifecycle callbacks. 3) In each method I have created within `onActivityCreated` / `onCreate` callbacks (i'm really speaking about any method I've created)... And in 2) + 3) cases, avoiding code dup...

Comment: ... dupplication is impossible. It's not good for maintenance... And it asks me for a lot of efforts... And I'm lazy... All these modifications only for the user's UI.... Omg... Too much for me. **(Update: precision -> `onActivityCreated` is for fragments and fragments dialogs, and `onCreate` for activities)**

Comment: I typically attach auth state listeners, instead of having checks against `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()` all over the place, but yeah... since the user's authentication state can change at any moment, you may need to check it in multiple places. You can limit this by, for example, attaching/detaching database listener based on auth state changes.

Comment: Typically, if I use https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener , it would allow me to know if the user has disconnected himself (or if he was disconnected for some reason), right? So it can replace all my checks. Right? Was you referring to this class?:)

Comment: That's an auth state listener indeed.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will be much easier if you are using BaseActivity and BaseFragment that all activities and fragment extends from it so you will write this code in BaseActivity/BaseFragment oncreate method only.

Comment: This could be handeled from server side first, let's say if user not authorized all apis return 404 error code so we can use interceptor in one place allover all the application  and when error code is 404 we navigate the user to login screen for example.